# Joint distribution function of max and min of independent, identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics, bivariate-distributions

Suppose we have independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with the same distribution. Let $F(\cdot)$ be the cumulative distribution of $X_i$ for all i
We are interested in the cumulative distribution of (Max,Min) where $\text{Max}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and similarly for min.
This is what I've worked out for far;

Let $G(x,y)$ the cumulative distribution of (Max,Min)

\begin{align}
G(x,y) & = P(\text{Max}\leq x, \text{Min} \leq y) \\[8pt]
& = P(\text{Max}\leq x) - P(\text{Max} \leq x, \text{Min} \gt y ) \\[8pt]
& = P(X_1 \leq x,\ldots,X_N \leq x) + P(y \lt X_1 \leq x) \\[8pt]
& = F^n(x) - [F(x) - F[y]]^n
\end{align}

Is this correct?
Thanks

Comment: looks reasonable to me

Comment: You have assumed $y \le x$

Comment: If $y \gt x$ then it's just $F^n(x)$?